# I Can´t boot into Ubuntu Strange Error

Tags: 10.10, boot

Somehow just after rebooting my PC, Ubuntu wouldn´t boot

Giving me this error, i seriously don´t know what happened but im sure it can be fixed

http://img209.imageshack.us/i/p2012101545.jpg/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can mean a corrupted filesystem. Boot the live CD and use it to check your root partition.
The root partition is the one that contains the Ubuntu.

For example you can check the filesystem on partition `/dev/sda1` with:

> sudo fsck /dev/sda1

If you're not sure which partition to take, you can list them with:

> sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda

where `sda` is your first disk, `sdb` second, etc...

Comment: so i just type the command press enter..and its done? ...will that fix this issue?

Comment: If there is no physical damage to the disk or you didn't mess around with partitions, then mostly yes :P