# Is My Filesystem Corrupt or Something?

Tags: filesystem, performance

OK, so for the past 2 days my Ubuntu Install (10.10) has been acting in a very strange manner.

Just after the login process is done, and the desktop is loading everything seems to be fine, it is fast and smooth like always, but then some 5 mins. later, it gets all choppy and slow, the mouse pointer it's slow,the apps won't respond to anything,and every aspect of the system is slow,even turning it off it's slow.

Some 2 days ago, [i asked a question here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18313/i-cant-boot-into-ubuntu-strange-error), about Ubuntu giving me an error, the person who answer my question, said that the filesystem might be corrupt and told me to do a check with a live cd,and so i did, i ran the fsck command and it actually fixed something.

However, this Problem, the sluggish performance just won't go away, i don't have any idea as to why this happened, but i'd like to know if there is  a permanent fix, or if im gonna have to install Ubuntu all over again.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since you say it runs fine for five minutes, that's your window of opportunity to get some monitoring tools running.

First, install iotop and htop :

> sudo apt-get install iotop htop

Then start a terminal for each and run them (just "iotop" and "htop", one in each terminal).  Then wait for the stuttering to start happening and see what causes it.

Another place to look might be dmesg - perhaps start a third terminal and run the command :

> tail -f /var/log/kern.log

(instead of just running "dmesg" directly, because you're interested in constantly monitoring the system as you wait for the stuttering to begin).

These steps should help pinpoint what might be causing your issues.