# not enough space on /boot for upgrade, even after purging old kernels and clearing files

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, upgrade

Okay, I'm a 'nix newbie, so at this point I don't really know what questions to ask, or what output would be relevant for y'all. This is also the first time I've ever posted on a forum to get help, as usually I have found all I've needed in previous questions and answers.

I'm dual booting Win8.1 and Ubuntu on a dell laptop. I have a separate /boot part that is 100mb. I tried to upgrade the kernel via the 'software updater' UI (don't know if that's relevant... I'm just trying to specify that I didn't use terminal), and it said that there was no space left on /boot. After researching a bit, I deleted the old kernels as well as `sudo apt-get clean` and emptying the trash and stuff. I rebuilt GRUB and rebooted. I tried to update again, and it says I still need to clear out some 30 or so MB off of /boot for the update.

I get the feeling from other posts that this is uncommonly large (people were saying they only had 13 MB used with multiple kernels?!)... and I don't know what else to remove from the /boot partition without screwing something up.

What am I missing here?

Comment: `apt-get clean` do not remove old kernels. Try with Ubuntu tweaks: http://askubuntu.com/a/584163/16395. By the way, why a separate `/boot` and why so small?

Comment: When I was installing Ubuntu, the site I read said to make a separate `/boot` because I was dual booting or something. I don't actually know... until today, I didn't know you didn't need to. :) And most folks seem to say that 100 megs was plenty big enough? *shrugs* Live and learn I guess.

Comment: Recommended size of a dedicated `/boot` partition for Ubuntu is 250 MB to 1 GB. In case you don't need it for any special purpose consider to [remove it](http://askubuntu.com/questions/30130/remove-boot-partition) or else try to [resize it](http://askubuntu.com/questions/280211/how-do-i-resize-my-boot-partition) after **making a full backup** (never change partition layouts without an up-to-date backup).

Comment: I almost wonder if I accidentally just didn't add enough zeroes to the partition size when making it originally. I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

1. Have a look [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/569679/whats-a-good-back-up-strategy-for-1-desktop-pc) for a good strategy on how to make system backups.  (I use http://CloneZilla.org)
2. Boot an Ubuntu LiveDVD and use the "try Ubuntu" option and then start `gparted` from the dash. (Or just boot a [gparted LiveCD](http://gparted.org/livecd.php) ).
   You will see something like this:

   [image]
3. The light yellow colour means "occupied" and the white means "free".  Click and drag one of the more empty partitions and make it smaller ("shrink") then "grow" your boot partition to 1GB.
4. Click the green check-mark icon (apply) and go to sleep.  In the morning everything should be ready.