# ubuntu 16.04lts lags to open terminal

Tags: 16.04, nvidia, bash, performance

why after my update to 16.04lts even opening the terminal is so slow?
it takes even 10/20seconds sometimes!

grapichs should be ok...
i got a i7 intel centrino with 6g of Ram and a nvidia geforce 540M (yes shitty optimus card)

even the boot is not fast as befere!

how can i trouble shooting this ?
cheers

Comment: Are you using the Nvidia or Intel graphics?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix nVidia

Comment: It is fairly well-established that Ubuntu upgrades tend to make systems slower-to-much-slower. I *highly recommend* backing up your data, and reinstalling. Other than that, there are few things you can do: http://askubuntu.com/questions/23942/ubuntu-slows-down-over-time. You may also need to clean up some old packages, programs, etc. that may be plaguing your old rusty hard drive.

Comment: Can you change your settings to Intel to isolate if problem is Nvidia or something else?

Comment: @PatrickNegus i didnt go for distro upgrade, apologize for misundertanding, this one is a fresh installation

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix `00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:0116] (rev 09) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller]) ` and the drivers for nvidia are  _nvidia binary 367.57 propietary and tested_

Comment: no suggestion? the lag is not to open the window but to waitin the blink promt and the path of the home in window...

Comment: Same problem here, though not fresh installation. It has started lately.